# convert parsefile image to byte in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, byte

Lets say I have a ParseFile "myimage"

How can I convert "myimage" from a ParseFile to byte[] type in android programming?

I am new to programming and parse.com on android. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

-edited-

I am trying to convert the ParseFile myimage to byte so I can pass it to my NewActivity.class

```
Bitmap bt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), myimage);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bt.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you add some code showing what you had done so far.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for your reply. I just edited my question with some code.

Comment: Your code seems right. Please post logcat error message. I think you are not getting parseFile properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getDataInBackground()` method of ParseFile to directly get byte[] from ParseImage.

```
ParseFile myImage;
myImage.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

  @override
  public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image", data);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {
       //byteArray not retrieved from parseImage handle the exception

    }
  }
});
```